# Customize SetPickerDateMode

Tags: objective-c, datepicker

Is it possible to set the `DatePickerMode` to just the Day of the Week (Monday - Sunday) and MM/dd/yyyy format? I can see the days of the week when I am using `UIPickerModeDateAndTime`, but in this case I dont need to select Time, Just the Dates with the days (if Monday-Sunday).

In other words, combining this two Modes (minus the time option)

[image: UIDatePickerModeDate]

[image: UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of customizing the UIDatePicker apart from that, but you can use a customized UIPickerView for it:

[UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

Find an example of using it here:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPickerView_Example